# Ho to run a .PY file on windows?

Tags: python

have been sent a **INIT**.py file.
So downloaded python 3.9.6 from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Click on file and selected open with python, a black command line window opens for about 1 second then closes.

I try opening python and running python documents/**INIT**.py
error python is not defined.

Why is it so difficult to run a python file and how do I make this file work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you open the python file? Also, it should be ```__init__.py```. If it is empty, then the python window would close

Comment: The window closes just because program execution has finished. You can add a pause at the end of your script. You can also open a console and run from there. But usually, you install Python and launch IDLE, or one of the nice free IDEs available.

Comment: An `__init__.py` file by itself is usually not very useful. The file name has a special meaning when it's part of a module in a directory with other Python files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a File Explorer window and go to the folder where INIT.py is.

Hold shift and right-click the background of the folder - not the .py file, just the empty part of the window. Choose "Open PowerShell window here".

Then type `python INIT.py`.

<sub>I personally prefer Command Prompt, but only PowerShell has an entry on the context menu in a default Windows installation. And yes, there are better ways to run Python programs, but this way should work on any Windows 10 installation with Python installed, regardless of how it's set up.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

before that do check if python 3.9.6 is installed properly and the python PATH is also added in Environment path.

in cmd go to the folder where the file is in then try.

```
python3 ./<file-name>.py
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python Not Defined

If you keep getting the message python not defined, then you probably forgot to check the option `Add Python To Path` which is shown below

[image]

I would recommend you to reinstall python and check this option to overcome this issue

---

## After You Reinstall Python

Just right-click on the .py file. You would surely get an option `Edit With IDLE` on hovering upon this option, you would notice on more option `Edit With IDLE 3.9(64-bit)`. Just select this option, and you would see your code. Press `F5` and your program would get executed.

[image]

Comment: @Jay Williams Is this problem solved?